# how to get the xpath for loading spinner

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have following dom .I need to find the element (*::before*). This before represents loading spinner . My element will be visible when this loading spinner is invisible .

```
<h3 class="text-center">
::before
</h3>
```

I am able to identify till h3 but not able to get this *:: before *.only :: before the part which goes from DOM once spinner is gone & my element is visible.
I have tried different xpath axes bit not able to reach this element

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, pseudo-elements like `::before` do not really exist in the DOM tree (hence the name), and therefore they cannot be selected using XPath. You need to use a CSS Selector instead:

```js
console.log(
  window.getComputedStyle(
      document.querySelector('h3'), ':before'
  )
);
```

```css
/* Add a heart before h3 */
h3::before {
  content: "♥";
}
```

```html
<h3 class="text-center">
H3
</h3>
```

And then use a `JavascriptExecutor` to inject the JS into the browser and [get the return value][1]:

```
String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('h3'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String content = (String) js.executeScript(script);
```